# Is it possible to generate the original files back from the minified JS file generated by webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify

I have lost my original react JS code files. All I have left with now is the final production minified JS file, which was generated from the original files using webpack. Is there any way that I could somehow unminify or generate back the original files from the availalbe minified file? I don't have any source mapping available.

Comment: You can [unminify](http://unminify.com/), but if it was mangled, you won't get your variable names back. Do you not use source control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no retained information about the old variable/methods names and so once you have minified, it can't be unminified back.

Answer (score 1):

Well thats "possible", but you won't be really able to read it.
You can try to use online "unminifier" tools e.g. http://unminify.com/ to pretty print your code.